# jquery get the value using class name

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of an input text field based on its class name through jquery.

the HTML is:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="datePicker" style="display: none;">
  <div class="dp_wrapper dp_input_6">
    <div class="dp_tagBox">
      <span class="dp_tag dp_tag_day">11</span>
      <span class="dp_tag dp_tag_month">Jun</span>
      <span class="dp_tag dp_tag_year">2009</span>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" onclick="GetContents()" value="submit">
</form>
```

The jquery is:

```
var myValue=$('.dp_tag dp_tag_day').val()
```

But `myValue` is coming up undefined. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var days_as_nums = parseInt($('.dp_tag_day', '.dp_input_6').text(), 10);
```

Comment: Added the base to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add + to get value like below.

var myValue = +$('.dp_tag dp_tag_day').val()

Answer (score -1):

`$('.dp_tag dp_tag_day')` is a `<span>`-Tag and you haven't the option `.val()`. Use this instead:

```
var myValue=$('.dp_tag.dp_tag_day').html()
```

This will return `11`.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably trying to get the text value of the span which is number of days in your case:

```
var myValue = $('.dp_tag.dp_tag_day').text();
```